# I want to make a div contain the default action (pressing <Enter> in this case) instead of having to create a button

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, haml

This is only a problem in IE8. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and even IE9. Anyway, I have a div on my app's login page that I have styled to look like a giant gray button. Here is the code:

```
.user_form .submit input[type=submit] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 11px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #4a5a64 url(/images/h1_background.gif) repeat-x;
  border: none;
}
```

And here is the haml code:

```
.submit
  = submit_tag 'Sign in', :class => 'no_style', :type => 'submit'
```

Since this works fine on all browswers with the sole exception of IE8, I was wondering if there was a way to fix this without converting this into a button, i.e., something like this in the haml:

```
.submit
  %button.submit_tag { bla bla bla } Sign In
```

Thank you!

Update: Here is ALL of my Haml code for the entire login page. As I said, in Firefox, Chrome and IE9, if you enter a user name and password and then press the Enter key, you then proceed to the welcome page (assuming, of course, that your user name and password are correct). In IE8, however, you just get a beep and you remain on the page.

```
- content_for :trackers do
  = google_analytics_standard_page_tracker
  = salesforce_tracker

- title 'Sign In', false

- form_for :session, :url => session_path, :html => { :class => 'user_form' } do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :email, 'Username'
    = f.text_field :email, :maxlength => 255, :autofocus => true
  .field
    = f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password

  .submit
    %input{ :type => 'submit', :value => 'Sign in' }

.section.right
  %ul.links
    %li= link_to 'Forgot password?', new_password_path
    %li= link_to 'Don\'t have an account? Sign up now', marketing_site_url("/index.php/buy-now")
    %li= link_to 'Resend activation email', resend_activation_path

  = render 'shared/need_help'
```

Comment: You know using a div to convey action is 100% inaccessible? This is really bad.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why it was done this way. I did not code this. I am simply cleaning up someone else's mess.

Comment: exactly what is not working in IE? Clearly the markup is not the problem according to the answer below. Maybe post the generated markup and remove the HAML tag?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is code my login page so that if the user hits the Enter key, it's as if he/she clicked the "Sign in" button. In other words, I want just hitting the Enter key to do the same thing. Like I said, this does behave like that in Firefox, Chrome and even IE9, just not IE8. In IE8, if I type in a user name and a password and then hit the Enter key, it just beeps, whereas in all other browsers, it goes to the Welcome page (assuming, of course, the user name and password are correct).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the raw HTML version but you will have to hand wire everything involved. Something like:

```
%input{:type => "submit", :value => "Add class"}
```

or if you like HTML style attributes

```
%input(type="submit" value="Add class")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I tried that, but it just would not work for IE8. I appreciate it very much though.